# Why gcc generates a PLT when it is apparently not needed?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, elf, dynamic-linking

Consider this code:

```
int foo();
int main() {
    foo();
    while(1){}
}
```

`int foo()` is implemented in a shared object.

Compiling this code with `gcc -o main main.c -lfoo -nostdlib -m32 -O2 -e main --no-pic -L./shared` gives the following diasm:

```
$ objdump -d ./main

./main:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .plt:

00000240 <.plt>:
 240:   ff b3 04 00 00 00       pushl  0x4(%ebx)
 246:   ff a3 08 00 00 00       jmp    *0x8(%ebx)
 24c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

00000250 <foo@plt>:
 250:   ff a3 0c 00 00 00       jmp    *0xc(%ebx)
 256:   68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
 25b:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmp    240 <.plt>

Disassembly of section .text:

00000260 <main>:
 260:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 264:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 267:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 26a:   55                      push   %ebp
 26b:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 26d:   51                      push   %ecx
 26e:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 271:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   272 <main+0x12>
 276:   eb fe                   jmp    276 <main+0x16>
```

With the following relocations:

```
$ objdump -R ./main

./main:     file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE 
00000272 R_386_PC32        foo
00001ffc R_386_JUMP_SLOT   foo
```

Note that:

1. The code was compiled with `--no-pic`, so it is not PIC
2. The call to `foo()`, in the `.text` section (`main` function), is **not** going through the PLT. Instead, it is just a simple `R_386_PC32` relocation that I assume it will directly be relocated to the address of the `foo` function at load time. It makes sense to me since the code is not PIC, so there is no need to add an extra indirection through the PLT.
3. Even without being used, the PLT is still being generated. An entry for `foo` is present there and we even have a `R_386_JUMP_SLOT` relocation to set up the `foo` entry in the GOT at load time (which the PLT points to).

My question is simple: I don't see the PLT being used anywhere in the code and I also don't see it being necessary here, so why does gcc creates it?

Comment: "I don't see the PLT being used anywhere" -- where is the _definition_ of `foo()` coming from? If it comes from `libfoo.so` (which the disassembly implies), then PLT _is_ necessary.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes, the definition of `foo()` comes from `libfoo.so`. I don't understand why the PLT is necessary in this case. The call to `foo()` is not pointing to the PLT. It is a direct `R_386_PC32` relocation. If I compile `main.c` with `-fpic`, then yes, I see the call pointing to its corresponding PLT entry and then I see a single `R_386_JUMP_SLOT` relocation

Comment: Also, the GOT pointer is not being prepared before calling `foo`. This seems to be the behavior when the module is not compiled with PIC. The original `main.o` object file only prepares the GOT pointer and asks for a `R_386_PLT32` relocation when it is compiled with `-fpic`. If it is compiled with `--no-pic`, it does not set up the GOT pointer anymore and then asks for a simple `R_386_PC32` relocation, as showed in the question. Based on this, it  seems to me that the dynamic linker will just add the relocation directly to the call in this case, I don't understand how it would be using the PLT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--no-pic` isn't like `-no-pie`, it seems to be a synonym for `-fno-pic` or `-fno-pie` affecting code-gen but not linking.  Assuming your distro's GCC defaults to making a PIE, you *are* making a PIE so there's no conversion of the call to `foo@plt`.

I get a linker warning `/tmp/ccyRsNtd.o: warning: relocation against 'getpid@@GLIBC_2.0' in read-only section '.text.startup'` / `warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE`.  (But the executable does run, unlike if it were 64-bit where `call rel32` isn't relocatable to the whole address space.)

And yeah, there is an unused PLT entry built by `ld` for some reason, but the way you're linking is totally nonstandard.

---

The normal reason for building a PLT is:

`ld` when linking a non-PIE will convert `call foo` into `call foo@plt` instead of including text relocations at every callsite that would require runtime fixups every time the program loads.

Use `-fno-plt` to get more efficient asm, especially for 64-bit mode where even PIE code can efficiently reference the GOT directly.

To make a simpler example, I used a function in libc (`getpid`) instead of a custom library.  Compiling normally with `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie -m32 -O2 foo.c`, I get 5-byte `e8 d5 ff ff ff` call rel32: `call   8049040 <getpid@plt>`.

But adding `-fno-plt` to that, I get 6-byte `ff 15 f4 bf 04 08  call [disp32]` - `call   DWORD PTR ds:0x804bff4`.  No PLT involved, just the GOT entry referenced with an absolute address.

No runtime relocation needed; this page of the `.text` section can stay "clean" as a file-backed private mapping of the executable.  (Runtime relocation would dirty it, making it backed only by swap space if the kernel wanted to evict that page.)

Also, it uses a "normal" GOT entry which needs early binding.  This does work even with `-nostdlib -lc` and the ill-advised `-e main` instead of calling it `_start` like a normal person.  Since it's a dynamically linked executable, the dynamic linker does run before your entry point and set up the GOT.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It makes sense to me, but I am not seeing such behavior when I compile `main.c` with `--no-pic`. I don't think `ld` is converting the call to `foo@plt`. It really seems that the call is just being directly relocated by the dynamic linker. To confirm that I even debugged the running program and saw that the `call` instruction is a near-call that is pointing directly to the procedure in the dynamic library. If, however, I compile `main.c` with `-fpic` and debug the running program, then the `call` goes through the PLT and I see the extra indirection.

Comment: "ld when linking a non-PIE will convert call foo into call foo@plt instead of including text relocations at every callsite that would require runtime fixups every time the program loads." - It seems that `ld` is not doing it in my case. The final binary that I posted in the question shows that there is a dynamic relocation `R_386_PC32` bound directly to the `call` instruction. If it was using the PLT, AFAIK it would already point to the PLT (with no relocation needed), and then there would be a single relocation bound to the PLT entry itself.

Comment: @felipeek: oh, yes, `--no-pic` isn't like `-no-pie`, it seems to be a synonym for `-fno-pic` or `-fno-pie` affecting code-gen but not linking.  I didn't use that because GCC doesn't document it.  But you're right, you *are* making a PIE so there's no conversion of the call to `foo@plt`.  Instead you get a linker warning `/tmp/ccyRsNtd.o: warning: relocation against 'getpid@@GLIBC_2.0' in read-only section '.text.startup'` / `warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE`.  So yeah, there is an unused PLT entry built by `ld` for some reason, but the way you're linking is totally nonstandard.

Comment: Now it makes more sense, thanks. `-fno-plt` works and it is indeed making all calls directly relative to the GOT, avoiding all of the lazy binding stuff. The only part that confuses me a bit is when you say that `ld` converts `foo` to `foo@PLT` only when linking a non-PIE. What would be the problem of using the PLT for PIE executables? AFAIK the relative PLT location can be calculated at link-time regardless of the load address of the program. Also, I tried linking the program using `-fno-pie -no-pie` and the PLT was generated and used normally (foo@PLT was there)

Comment: @felipeek: When making an ELF shared object (including a PIE), the object files are expected to *already* reference `foo@PLT` if that's what's desired / needed.  So that's what GCC does normally in its asm source, for functions not in the current compilation unit: https://godbolt.org/z/f17vr1.  If `ld` finds the target function is found in another `.o`, it can "relax" the call to not use the PLT.  (If you compiled with `-fno-plt`, there's an extra byte it has to fill; it uses a `67` address-size prefix to pad the `call rel32` to fit the space of a `call [disp32]` or `call [RIP + rel32]`)

Comment: @felipeek: Only when linking a non-PIE executable does `ld` handle PLT generation if it turns out the symbol isn't found in one of the static objects, same `call printf` that works with static linking.  Also: [Return value of get\_pc\_thunk not being used](//stackoverflow.com/a/62827295) - "hidden" ELF visibility will promise the compiler that the call will be statically resolvable at link time, so even `-fno-plt` will avoid a PLT or GOT reference that needs to be relaxed.  (oh, that was your question :P)  Also [slightly related](//stackoverflow.com/q/61553723) re: PIE history and static-PIE.

Comment: "Only when linking a non-PIE executable does ld handle PLT generation": very interesting, I think this explains the strange behaviors that I was seeing. If I generate `main.o` with `-fno-pie`, the relocation does not go through the PLT. And, in fact, if I link the binary with `-no-pie`, the linker does generate the PLT and makes the `call` instruction to point to the PLT, even though the relocation was not `R_386_PLT32`. If I link the binary without `no-pie` (defaulting to PIE), the linker makes the `call` instruction point directly to the func in the shared object, but...

Comment: ...still creates the PLT for some weird reason. This was my original question, but there were a lot of flags misleading my understanding. I didn't realise that the final executable was still being compiled as PIE even when passing `--no-pic` to `ld`. In fact I think `ld` does not care about leaving the PLT there in this case because it is not common to compile the object files without PIE and then generate the binary with PIE. Thank you so much!

Comment: @felipeek: yup, that sounds right.  If you want to post an answer with any details I left out from my quick answer, now that you've got it more sorted out, feel free.  Otherwise these comments will hopefully be enough for any future readers.